# How to call Array Adapter in Fragment in Android?

Tags: android

This is my class, please see the below code and give me suggestion 
it is in Android in below code I create **Adapter** class I want to access it in **fragment**

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private String responsedate[];
    private String responsecheckinto[];
    private String responsemessage[];
    private Activity context;
    //Context mcontext;
    ImageView pdf;
    public Adapter(Activity context, String[] responsedate, String[] responsecheckinto, String[] responsemessage) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_response, responsedate);
        this.context = context;
        this.responsedate = responsedate;
        this.responsecheckinto = responsecheckinto;
        this.responsemessage = responsemessage;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_response, null, true);
        TextView ResponseDate=(TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
        TextView checkito=(TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtcheckintoText);
        TextView message=(TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        TextView view=(TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.documents);
        view.setText("Document");
        ResponseDate.setText(responsedate[position]);
        checkito.setText(responsecheckinto[position]);
        message.setText(responsemessage[position]);
        pdf=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.pdf);
        pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Adams_advice_Fragment fragment = new Adams_advice_Fragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
        return  listViewItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the actual problem you faced?

Comment: What your problem then?

Answer (score 0):

**Pass context as getActivity()**

customAdapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), .......);

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you want to access this adapters click event in your fragment where you can take some action. And this should be the case as the adapter should pass on the events to client instead of consuming it itself.

To do that you need to have a callback mechanism. Create an interface

```
public interface IOnListItemClickListener {
        void onListItemClicked();
}
```

in your adapter class

```
 private IOnListItemClickListener mListItemClickListener;

 public void setListItemClickListener(IOnListItemClickListener listItemClickListener) {
    mListItemClickListener = listItemClickListener;
 }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_response, null, true);
    TextView ResponseDate=(TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
    TextView checkito=(TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtcheckintoText);
    TextView message=(TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    TextView view=(TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.documents);
    view.setText("Document");
    ResponseDate.setText(responsedate[position]);
    checkito.setText(responsecheckinto[position]);
    message.setText(responsemessage[position]);
    pdf=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.pdf);
    pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(null != mListItemClickListener) {
                 mListItemClickListener.onListItemClicked();
            }
        }
    });
    return  listViewItem;
}
```

Then you can take any action accordingly in your fragment once you receive callback